# Why did moderators and other members lose reputation points during the few days?

Tags: support, reputation

I notice that some moderators and other members lost reputation points (at least 250 points) during the last few days.

Why did they lose them? Is it a bug on the site?

Comment: Lots of users across the network were affected. You can read more on this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the link. I didn't know that it had happened in so many sites. But a question remains: how can the system know that the user(s) deleted/removed did engage in voter fraud on all questions? Maybe it was only on some questions.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio the "voting fraud" phrase is not always correct. It's just the SE staff decided not to preserve all of the user's votes after reviewing it. For more info and clarity, read the answer from the SE staff on [Please update the text in help for “User was Removed” reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328674)

Comment: I doubt it was "voting fraud" at all. I've lost more than 800 rep, that can hardly be from a single user's "voting fraud" (that should at least have been detected much earlier then) – though that seems to be the (rare) case here according to Meta.SE. AFAIK, if a user (or a question) is deleted only reputation younger than X (IIRC 90 days or 180 days) would be removed. TL;DR: as it was a network-wide thing, Meta.SE is the best place to seek clarification – the question Firelord linked to should be a good starting point.

Comment: I personally lost 120 rep due to a "user deletion".